# How can I increase the number of words suggested by the text prediction feature in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, autocomplete, productivity

I use the [text prediction feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2lhk.jpg) in Windows 10:

[image]

How can I increase number of words suggested by the text prediction feature in Windows 10?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is currently no option to increase number of words suggested by the text prediction feature in Windows 10. The prediction feature doesn't have this capability.